# Algorithm to Parse CAML xml

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint-2010, caml

I have a particular requirement to parse Sharepoint CAML and produce something else. 
The first scenario is to produce an SQL Query.

Are there any best practice dev tools/algorithms when parsing XML? I am thinking of using Linq To Xml as my tool. But not sure if there is a better approach for such type of parsing.

Another approach I like is that the one used by the OpenXML SDK where they have built a strongly typed engine around the Open XML format.  Perhaps I could build something similar but it could be a little far fetched.

Any assistance (perhaps previous experience on xml parsing) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading any structure in any format, you have to find the optimal traversal mechanism. In this case, since CAML Logical Operations are binary (have 2 children only), a particular traversal mechanism can be adopted. Linq to XML is a powerful tool for traversing XML.